# Three.js texturing from image in google colab not working as expected

Tags: three.js, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use the TensorflowGraphics implementation of Three.js in google colab to apply an image to a mesh, but while it can handle modifying the color when I try to load an image it does not work and I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Here is the code:

```
context = threejs_visualization.build_context()
default_material = context.THREE.MeshPhongMaterial.new_object({
  'map':context.THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(samplesfn + "missing_tex.png")
})
default_material['vertexColors'] = context.THREE.NoColors

mesh["material"] = default_material
_ = threejs_visualization.triangular_mesh_renderer(mesh, width=100, height=100)
```

threejs_visualization.triangular_mesh_renderer is provided at https://github.com/tensorflow/graphics/blob/master/tensorflow_graphics/notebooks/threejs_visualization.py

I know the problem is not that the image can't be loaded properly as in the same file openCV can load it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this syntax, but I believe you should be able to change the material color by simply [modifying the `.color` property](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=phong#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.color) instead of dealing with vertex colors:

```js
default_material = context.THREE.MeshPhongMaterial.new_object({
  'map':context.THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(samplesfn + "missing_tex.png"),
  'color': 0xff9900 // Set to orange
});
```

#### Lights

PhongMaterial needs to be illuminated by lights if you're going to use the `map` property. Materials don't usually glow by themselves, they need lights for you to see them. [See here for a demo of a simple light setup](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=lights#webgl_lights_hemisphere)

If you want your texture to "glow" instead of reflecting light, set your texture to [the `emmissiveMap` property](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=phong#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.emissiveMap), instead of `map`.

Comment: im actually already able to modify the color properly, the issue is that when setting the map with a texture it fails

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you added lights to your scene? Also, are you getting any console errors that say the image failed to load?

Comment: I didn't add any lights, and no it isn't saying the Image failed to load

Comment: Ah, there's your problem. You could add lights, or make your texture emissive. See above, I expanded on my original answer.